# Optimizing Android Build in Jenkins

Tags: android, gradle, jenkins

Currently we have an android build automation run in Jenkins, the current implementation is to run a clean build every time. But as the project grows, we experienced a very long build time since doing a clean build means we can't take advantage of the gradle's incremental build feature.

We are considering not to run clean build for every builds, yet we are concerned about the potential instabilities caused by cache corruption and similar problems which will then require manual intervention. Is there any way for us to speed up the build process? Or this tradeoff is actually common and acceptable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you test the caching behavior. Think about how you can use different build executors and/ or label configurations in Jenkins. You can have one test job that builds with the cache enabled along keeping the original job with clean-builds only and test for a certain time-span.
This test should also reflect the different build machine types of the project.
Without more details here, it is hard to answer. But depending on project size and configuration, bad cache behavior is possible. Ideally, you have then also some way how you could easily discover and debug cache issues if they happen.